# Why does netbeans freeze when I'm trying to type?

Tags: netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 6.7 on win xp*. I'm not really sure what the pattern is, but lately performance has gotten really bad to the point where it's almost unusable. Any ideas for where to look for slowdowns?

Intel Core Duo 2.2 GHz, 3.5 GB or ram, accoring to the system properties panel. 90 GB of free hard disk space.

Comment: The same on Netbeans 7.1.1 (Ubuntu 64bit - OpenJDK). The CPU is on 100% after every modification.

Answer (score 4):

NetBeans 6.5 "leaks" temporary files. It creates temporary files in `%TEMP%` (typically `c:\\Documents and Settings\\*username*\\Local Settings\\Temp`) and does not delete them. When enough files accumulate, access to the temporary directory slows to a crawl. That in turn drags NB down to a crawl.

To clean it up:

- Shut down NetBeans
- Open a command prompt and type:

  ```
  cd %TEMP%  
  del *.java  
  del *.form  
  del output*  
  del *vcs*
  ```

**Important:**

- Do not try to do this with windows explorer. It won't work.
- The deletes can take several minutes each. Be patient.

This is much better in 6.7 and I have not seen it at all in 6.8.

Comment: Experienced this in Netbeans 6.9 RC1 and your solution worked to solve it.

Comment: Where are these files in Windows 7?  I found a ton of what appear to be changesets in `C:\Users\[user]\.netbeans\7.0\var\filehistory`  I'm wondering if these are slwoing down netbeans

Comment: On my system it's [user]\AppData\Local\Temp. The files in .netbeans\7.0\var\filehistory are the local file history. That shouldn't bother NB since it's only used if you explore the local change history (right click on file name and choose Local History). You can disable the local history via Tools->Plugins->Installed->Local History->Disable. You can change the retention period with Tools->Options->Misc->Versioning->Local History.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on java6 you can use the jconsole app to connect to your running netbeans instance and see among other things, what the threads are doing, memory usage and whether you're in a race condition.