# Frequent Netbeans freezes

Tags: java, ide, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 6.8 for PHP projects located on network drives in a Windows network. Frequently, the IDE gets really slow (like a temporary freeze) to a point where it's totally unusable. At first it seems like a total crash, but after some time (might be sevaral minutes) the IDE works again as before.

This happens with Netbeans 6.7 as well as 6.8 on my Windows XP 32-bit installation. I'm using Java 1.6.0_13.

This is a fresh Netbeans installation, so it can't have to do with too many temp files. I assume it has to do with the frequent code checks that Netbeans does. It's probably not very fast when doing this over the network connection. But it can't be that this feature renders the IDE useless...

This thread deals with the same issue http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=5548. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: You can often see where NetBeans is broken by getting a stack trace with `ctrl-\`, `ctrl-break`, `jstack`, `visualvm` or other means. I've seen it use a `WeakHashMap` as a cache, which could be the problem here, because once HotSpot really optimises it the entries are removed immediately after they are added. I have also seen it come to grief using reflection very badly.

Comment: Hope This Helps [LINK](http://quattrobrain.blogspot.com/2015/03/fix-netbeans-freezehang-problem.html#:~:text=1.,memory%20from%20the%20program's%20location.)

Answer (score 5):

A co-worker just showed me within `Tools -> Plugins` there are a lot of plugins I don't use for PHP development.  Disable the ones you don't use and it'll speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [Why Does NetBeans Freeze When I'm Trying to Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675628/why-does-netbeans-freeze-when-im-trying-to-type/1828937#1828937)

I have not seen this behavior in 6.8 editing Java, but I haven't done much PHP, so it could still be there.

Comment: As you can see in my description, this is a fresh Netbeans install. So I don't assume it has to do with Temp-files. Besides that, you write in your answer that it's much better in 6.7 and 6.8, I'm using the latter one...

Comment: I missed the part about network drives. I did see an issue with this but have never been able to reproduce it. It manifested as very slow behavior, and running WireShark showed a lot of SMB traffic. My guess was that it was an issue between the clocks on the machines involved. I think NB always thought the files on the drive were newer than its cached information and kept rescanning.

Comment: i had an issue with netbeans freezing when i opened css files.  since there were a couple of other java applications that also froze (but were working before), I retraced my steps and found that I had too many fonts installed.  so this is a java issue, not netbeans.  but netbeans (even if you are using for php) is still a java app so it is affected.

Answer (score 0):

My NetBeans periodically used the processor at 100% for a few minutes (not remember or 6.8, but in 6.9.1 exactly). The problem disappeared when appointed filter in the panel "Tasks" (Ctrl-6) at the bottom (default) of the window. That is in "Filter the task list" disabled display "Tasks" and appointed a filter for a fixed number for TODO (field "Limit visible items per type to:").